# Why does Enum need to use a CType?

Tags: vb.net, enums

In vb.net, I got an Enum defined As Integer:

```
    Enum enUtilityTypeDetailStudentEntryWorkflow As Integer
        enUTDSEW_Default = 379
        enUTDSEW_ApplicantRecordBook = 380
    End Enum
```

I would like to assign the Enum directly to a variable but it does not work.

```
        EntryWorkflowLookUpEdit.EditValue = enUtilityTypeDetailStudentEntryWorkflow.enUTDSEW_Default
```

I ended up using a CType and converting it to an Integer.

```
        EntryWorkflowLookUpEdit.EditValue = CType(enUtilityTypeDetailStudentEntryWorkflow.enUTDSEW_Default, Integer)
```

This works but it adds a lot of noise to the code and it seems like the Enum is already defined as an Integer, making me think, why do I have to assign it again?

Is there other ways to accomplish this without all the noise?
I know I am missing something here.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enum is defined as using an integer as its underlying type.

It's a *good thing* that this is an explicit conversion IMO, because it means you don't *accidentally* end up using an enum value where you really *meant* to just use a straight integer. The point of enums is to effectively have different "views" of numbers - and changing which "view" you're using should be explicit.

I would expect there to be *relatively* few such conversions in most codebases.

If this becomes a significant issue for you, you could always write an extension method of `ToInt32` or something like that, which just performed the cast.

Personally if I were trying to reduce the noise in this code, I'd try to find a shorter name than `enUtilityTypeDetailStudentEntryWorkflow` - and one which conformed with the .NET naming conventions, at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I am still trying to grasp some of the concepts. It gets annoying when you add it in and it just does nothing (no errors, etc.) but a few lines up it can be used in an IF statement and not have to have CType. I am going to have to do some more reading on this. Do you (or anyone else) have any resources recommendations that I can review?

Comment: On the Naming Convention, I must admit, I was a like a sheep following what others have done before me (there are hundreds of Enums formatted similarly) but I think it makes sense to follow the .NET Naming Conventions. I am going to change my Enum and mention it to the other developers. It is silly to have a prefix not only once but twice!

Comment: @Gerhard: I don't know any particular resources around this - I'd just look in MSDN, to be honest.